# C# : OperationCanceledException : The operation was canceled

Tags: c#, async-await, azure-eventhub

Below I am trying to send data to eventhub, it works for few minutes and then the *OperationCanceledException* is thrown. Any hint on where I am wrong in using CancellationToken (if that is what I should be using)? or how I could fix this issue?

```
public async void send<T>(IEnumerable<T> list, string eventhubname)
{                
     var token = new CancellationTokenSource();
     CancellationToken ct = token.Token;
     EventHubProducerClient producer = null;

     try
     {

        producer = new EventHubProducerClient(this._connectionString, eventhubname);

        var eventBatch = await producer.CreateBatchAsync(ct); **Line 148 here**
        foreach (T item in list)
        {
            eventBatch.TryAdd(new EventData(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(item.ToString())));
        }
       await producer.SendAsync(eventBatch);
       await producer.DisposeAsync();
     }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
       //($"Error While sending message to Event Hub: { ex.Message}", ex);
        if (producer != null)
        {
            await producer.DisposeAsync();
        }
        if (ct.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
        token.Dispose();
        throw new TaskCanceledException(ex.Message);
        }
        throw;
    }
}
```

Following is the Exception stalk

```
System.OperationCanceledException: The operation was canceled.
   at Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.AmqpCbsLink.SendTokenAsyncResult.<>c__DisplayClass13_0.<GetAsyncSteps>b__3(SendTokenAsyncResult thisPtr, IAsyncResult r)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.IteratorAsyncResult`1.StepCallback(IAsyncResult result)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.AmqpCbsLink.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<SendTokenAsync>b__1(IAsyncResult a)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at Azure.Messaging.EventHubs.Amqp.AmqpConnectionScope.<CreateSendingLinkAsync>d__63.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Azure.Messaging.EventHubs.Amqp.AmqpConnectionScope.<OpenProducerLinkAsync>d__58.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Azure.Messaging.EventHubs.Amqp.AmqpProducer.<CreateLinkAndEnsureProducerStateAsync>d__32.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.FaultTolerantAmqpObject`1.<OnCreateAsync>d__6.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.Singleton`1.<GetOrCreateAsync>d__13.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.Singleton`1.<GetOrCreateAsync>d__13.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Azure.Messaging.EventHubs.Amqp.AmqpProducer.<CreateBatchAsync>d__29.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Azure.Messaging.EventHubs.Producer.EventHubProducerClient.<CreateBatchAsync>d__42.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at <send>d__20`1.MoveNext() in  line 148
```

Comment: You don't take into consideration unmanaged resources, anything that implements the IDisposable Interface you should Dispose of explicitly. The `using` command is a neat way of doing this:  `using EventDataBatch eventBatch`. Without the `using` your code could be exhausting the heap. That's a guess whats the `ex.InnerException.Message`?

Comment: I am not sure why you are passing a token anyway, also, this could be the internal workings of the eventhub, are you getting connection issues or something? Is the token actually in a cancelled state (im guessing not)

Answer (score 3):

An `OperationCanceledException` exception typically means that an Event Hubs service operation timed out.  In your stack trace, it appears that the client is timing out while attempting to establish the AMQP link to the service and send the authorization token.

This often indicates that there is an issue with network communication to the service.  Without more context around the environment that your code is running in, I can only speculate as to the cause.

One common case is when running in environments, such as Xamarin Android, where raw TCP communication cannot be used.  Another common case is when running in environments with firewall rules filtering outgoing connections.  For a TCP transport, you'd need to ensure that the standard AMQP ports, 5671 and 5672, are open and can be used for outgoing connections.

To work around both scenarios, you may want to try setting the [`TransportType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.messaging.eventhubs.eventhubconnectionoptions.transporttype?view=azur-dotnet#Azure_Messaging_EventHubs_EventHubConnectionOptions_TransportType) on your [`EventHubProducerClientOptions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.messaging.eventhubs.producer.eventhubproducerclientoptions?view=azure-dotnet) to `EventHubsTransportType.AmqpWebSockets`.

For example:

```cs
var options = new EventHubClientOptions();
options.ConnectionOptions.TransportType = EventHubsTransportType.AmqpWebSockets;

await using var producer = new EventHubProducerClient(
    "<< CONNECTION STRING >>", 
    "<< EVENT HUB NAME >>", 
    options);

// MORE CODE...
```

One important thing that I'd like to mention about your snippet is that you're potentially losing data.  Because you're ignoring the return value to `TryAdd`, in the case that you're passing in an enumerable that is larger than what can be sent in a single batch, you are silently failing to add them.

I'd suggest that you either consider respecting the return from `TryAdd` or use the `SendAsync` overload that accepts a set of events.  In the previous case, if `TryAdd` returns `false`, then you know the batch is full and that you should break up your set into multiple batches.  In the latter case, if the set is too large to be sent in a single call, the call will fail.

For some additional thoughts:

- I don't see a reason why you would need to create the cancellation token, as you're not using it to request that the send be cancelled, so you can likely skip that step.
- The producer client allows for disposal for convenience; like the `HttpClient`, it is valid to use as a long-lived client.  In the case that you're sending data over a period of time, I'd recommend creating it once and then only closing/disposing once your application is closing or you're done sending for a while.
- The `EventDataBatch` is disposable and does hold a reference to unmanaged items.  I'd recommend ensuring that you dispose that when a send operation is complete.

Putting some of that feedback into action, while keeping the producer scoped to the single method call, an example would look something like:

```cs
public async void Send<T>(IEnumerable<T> data, string eventHubName)
{      
    var options = new EventHubClientOptions();
    options.ConnectionOptions.TransportType = EventHubsTransportType.AmqpWebSockets; 
         
    await using var producer = new EventHubProducerClient(
        this._connectionString, 
        eventHubName, 
        options);

    try
    {
        var eventSet =
            data.Select(item => new EventData(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(item.ToString()));

        await producer.SendAsync(eventSet).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log($"Error While sending message to Event Hub: { ex.Message}", ex);
        throw;
    }
}
```

For more comprehensive examples, you may want to take a look at:

- [Event Hubs sample for creating a client with custom options](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/master/sdk/eventhub/Azure.Messaging.EventHubs/samples/Sample02_ClientWithCustomOptions.cs)
- [Event Hubs sample for publishing multiple batches](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/master/sdk/eventhub/Azure.Messaging.EventHubs/samples/Sample04_PublishMultipleEventBatches.cs)

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed response.