# Why am I getting an OperationCanceledException on Me.GetAsync() when using GraphServiceClient in C#?

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to get the user information from Graph. But every time I call Me.GetAsync() for my GraphServiceClient I get an OperationCanceledException: "The operation was canceled."

```
var authenticationProvider = new BaseBearerTokenAuthenticationProvider(new TokenProvider());
GraphServiceClient GraphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authenticationProvider);
var user = await GraphClient.Me.GetAsync();
```

The TokenProvider is able to get an access token.

```
class TokenProvider : IAccessTokenProvider
{
    private IPublicClientApplication _PCA;
    private string[] _Scopes;
    public TokenProvider()
    {
        _PCA = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(OAuthSettings.ApplicationId)
                                             .WithRedirectUri(OAuthSettings.RedirectUri).Build();
        _Scopes = OAuthSettings.Scopes.Split(' ');
        AllowedHostsValidator = new AllowedHostsValidator();
    }
    public async Task<string> GetAuthorizationTokenAsync(Uri uri,
                                                         Dictionary<string, object> additionalAuthenticationContext = default,
                                                         CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        var accounts = await _PCA.GetAccountsAsync();
        AuthenticationResult result;
        try
        {
            result = await _PCA.AcquireTokenSilent(_Scopes, accounts.FirstOrDefault()).ExecuteAsync();
            return result.AccessToken;
        }
        catch (MsalUiRequiredException ex)
        {
            var interactiveRequest = _PCA.AcquireTokenInteractive(_Scopes);
            interactiveRequest = interactiveRequest.WithParentActivityOrWindow(AuthUIParent);
            result = await interactiveRequest.ExecuteAsync();
            return result.AccessToken;
        }
    }

    public AllowedHostsValidator AllowedHostsValidator { get; }
}
```

I've compared this to the official Microsoft documentation which looks identical.
And I've already switched to another internet connection to rule out any blockings from a firewall but without any difference in the error message.

Comment: Do you get the Exception directly or after a Connection Timeout? Is there something in between you and the internet like a Proxy?

Comment: The exception occurs with no other prior timeouts. But between invoking the function and the exception, 5 minutes pass. So this seems like a timeout itself.
And there is nothing inbetween me and the internet.

Comment: Something is either not responding or deadlocking. Are you doing sync-over-async anywhere? Like `.Result` or `.Wait`?

Comment: No .Result() or .Wait() anywhere in this process. Everything is done with async and await.

Comment: Similar issue;https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62649608/c-sharp-operationcanceledexception-the-operation-was-canceled